# Some parameters passed using Docker compose to Memgraph are ignored

Tags: docker, memgraphdb

I'm trying to pass parameters using Docker compose to Memgraph. This what my docker compose file looks like:

```
 version: "3"
services:
  memgraph-platform:
    image: "memgraph/memgraph-platform"
    ports:
      - "7687:7687"
      - "3000:3000"
      - "7444:7444"
    volumes:
      - mg2_lib:/var/lib/memgraph
      - mg2_log:/var/log/memgraph
      - mg2_etc:/etc/memgraph

    environment:
      - MEMGRAPH="--memory-limit=256 --log-level=TRACE"

    entrypoint: ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
    
volumes:
  mg2_lib:
  mg2_log:
  mg2_etc:
```

I can't find the log files after this. If I omit `--memory-limit=256` from compose file than I can find the log files. It looks like parameters are ignored. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does supervisord reset the environment for each process it controls?  Overriding the `entrypoint:` like this seems a little unusual, does deleting the `entrypoint:` line help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DavidMaze it didn't help, but updating version to 3.8 did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some issues with version 3 of Docker reading only the first flag of the environment variables. Try upgrading to version 3.8 and separating your variables into a `.env` file. Your `docker-compose` file would then look something like this:

```
 version: "3.8"
services:
  memgraph-platform:
    image: "memgraph/memgraph-platform"
    ports:
      - "7687:7687"
      - "3000:3000"
      - "7444:7444"
    volumes:
      - mg2_lib:/var/lib/memgraph
      - mg2_log:/var/log/memgraph
      - mg2_etc:/etc/memgraph

    env_file:
      - /.env

    entrypoint: ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
    
volumes:
  mg2_lib:
  mg2_log:
  mg2_etc:
```

and your `.env` file:

```
MEMGRAPH="--memory-limit=256 --log-level=TRACE"
```